# Is there a way to configure an iPhone is an iBeacon in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am making a small project that can configure an iOS device as an iBeacon to broadcast Bluetooth signals.

**Problem:**
The Bluetooth code for configuring the device as an iBeacon to broadcast BLE signals is throwing 2 errors that I can't seem to fix, the error messages are below. These errors are what's stopping the iOS device from being configured into an iBeacon.

**Message 1:**
"[CoreBluetooth] API MISUSE: <CBPeripheralManager: 0x28206c0c0> can only accept this command while in the powered on state"

**Message 2:**
"[CoreBluetooth] XPC connection invalid"

If someone could assist me in getting my app to work that would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to use a CBPeripheralManager object to configure the device as an iBeacon. Both of the error messages are stemming from this object.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can ignore the second error. The first error is your problem; you are trying to perform Core Bluetooth operations before you have received the `.poweredOn` state in your peripheral delegate. You need to show the code where you set up beacon advertising.

Comment: Note that an iPhone cannot be an iBeacon. That's a specific service, and you can't set that up in an app. But, it is possible to advertise as a BLE peripheral, which I believe is what you actually want. Apple provides a full example: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/transferring_data_between_bluetooth_low_energy_devices